# VB: Index outside bounds of array while trying to read csv into a datagrid

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

I'm attempting to print on a datagrid from a csv file and i'm getting a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'" error on the PhNumber column. When i delete this column the error then moves to the 'age' column. What exactly am I doing wrong here? I assumed it was an error with how i had written the csv, but i've checked a thousand times and I can't find anything.

```
Vannessa Sanchez,23,Physics Methods Specialist,85.30,44 Garden Place KURRACA WEST Victoria 3518,(03) 9270 3392
Usnavi de la Vega,29,Biology Chemistry,90.55,66 Hebbard Street KNOXFIELD Victoria 3180,(03) 9270 3392
Benny Smith,24,Physics,88.35,31 Cambridge Street MULGRAVE Victoria,(03) 4745 6684
Nina Rosario,20,English History,88.75,96 Boughtman Street FERNTREE GULLY Victoria 3156,(03) 9293 4908
Alexander Hamilton,40,English,82.45,40 South Street HASTINGS Victoria 3915,03 5550 0388
Thomas Jefferson,32,French English,92.95,69 Parkes Road DANDENONG Victoria 3004,(03) 8694 7835
John Adams,57,Chemistry Methods,84.25,25 Hodgson St CLAYTON Victoria 3168,(03) 4560 8693
Eliza Schuyler,31,Physics Methods,94.95,68 Weigall Avenue OAKLEIGH VICTORIA 3166,(03) 8395 6353



Public Class Form1
Dim TutorTable As New DataTable
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With TutorTable
        .Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("Age", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("Subjects", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("ATAR", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("Location", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("PhNumber", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Reader As New IO.StreamReader("D:\Users\user\Downloads\TutorData.csv", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
    Dim StringLine As String = ""
    Do
        StringLine = Reader.ReadLine
        If StringLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Dim Columns() As String = StringLine.Split(",")
        Dim NewRow As DataRow = TutorTable.NewRow
        NewRow("Name") = Columns(0)
        NewRow("Age") = Columns(1)
        NewRow("Subjects") = Columns(2)
        NewRow("ATAR") = Columns(3)
        NewRow("Location") = Columns(4)
        NewRow("PhNumber") = Columns(5)
        TutorTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)
    Loop
    Reader.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = TutorTable
    Me.Text = TutorTable.Rows.Count & "rows"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? What's the content of Columns? Set a breakpoint on line `Dim NewRow As DataRow = TutorTable.NewRow` and tell us.

Comment: The code sample and data you provided work absolutely fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure that none of your data is missing a comma?

Comment: BTW upvoted for asking a well structured question so we can try to reproduce what's going on.

Comment: When your code hangs, hover your mose over the Columns array in the line `Dim Columns() As String = StringLine.Split(",")` to see how many elements there are in the array.

Comment: You data is missing a comma or you are reading an empty string. Your `If StringLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do` won't help here. Substitute it with `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(StringLine) Then Exit Do`. Also, parse the whole file, without storing any data, and write to the Console (`Console.WriteLine(Columns.Length)`) each line where the array length is less than 6. Add a line counter in the loop to see where that happens.

Comment: The piece of the csv you have shown us does not have missing or extra comma's so that should work just fine. I suggest loading the csv in Excel so it would become easier to spot where the columns are shifted. It could be in a name somewhere like `Doe, John` where you expect it to be `John Doe`

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of Columns immediately after the .Split. Branch to a Function to fix the data.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
        Dim Columns() As String = StringLine.Split(",")
        If Columns.Length < 6 Then
            ReDim Preserve Columns(5)
            Columns = FixMissingData(Columns)
        End If
        Dim NewRow As DataRow = TutorTable.NewRow
        'and the rest of your code
End Sub
Private Function FixMissingData(arrColumns As String()) As String()
        'Code to parse fields, probably using RegEx
        'reassign values to correct Columns index, fill empty data columns with and empty string or default value
        'such as "missing data"
        Return arrColumns
End Function
```